# Is Intel Z690 a true or fake RAID?

Tags: windows-11, raid-1, intel

I've got a mainboard with the [Intel Z690 chipset](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/218833/intel-z690-chipset.html) and I'm considering RAID-1, but while reading about it I found that one should be careful not to do this with fake-RAID as it would mean performance hit for writing.

Does this apply to this chipset or is it a true RAID and I shouldn't worry?

Comment: Z690 supports RAID 0,1,5,10. The best is to check out your motherboard's manual for setup. The BIOS should not let you choose a setup which is not fully supported.  [Here's a Tutorial](https://tech4gamers.com/how-to-raid-on-intel-z690-chipset/) for Gigabyte motherboards.

Comment: Should you worry in the first place? Even if it's software RAID, do you expect a significant performance hit on a modern CPU in a mode that doesn't even calculate parity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by all accounts a true hardware RAID.

Some cautions :

- [No RAID support for SATA drives, only NVMe](https://community.intel.com/t5/Rapid-Storage-Technology/No-RAID-support-for-SATA-drives-only-NVMe-3/m-p/1377148)
  says:

  > we don’t support 4K sector at this time, so it does require a 512 byte sector size in order to create a RAID array
- [PRO Z690-A BIOS update/reset breaks RAID Volume](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?threads/pro-z690-a-bios-update-reset-breaks-raid-volume.378783/)
  discusses the ugly part of a hardware RAID, where on this model any
  BIOS/UEFI update can destroy the RAID and lose you all your data.

Comment: Oh, the second bullet sounds pretty scarry. Excactly what one wants to mitigate with a RAID 1. As my mainboard is by ASRrock, I'll ask in their forums whether their bios has similar issues.